# HANA database - Injection of a Table User Defined Function into a lateral join

Tags: hana, lateral-join

### In short

On an HANA database, I have set a Table User Defined Function which returns a 1-row table with 3 columns ;
I would like to use it inside a `lateral join` but so far my attempts have been to no avail.

### The problem

Let's say we have the following dummy Table User Defined Function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  PBANALYST.  F__ITEM_MBEW(
    IN
        p_str_MATNR                 NVARCHAR(18)
    ,   p_str_BWKEY                 NVARCHAR(02)
    ,   p_str_VALDATE               NVARCHAR(08)
)

RETURNS
    TABLE(
        VALDATE     NVARCHAR(08)
    ,   LBKUM       INTEGER
    ,   VERPR       DECIMAL
    ,   STPRS       DECIMAL
    )

LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
SQL SECURITY INVOKER


AS
BEGIN

    RETURN
        SELECT
            '20220928'  AS  VALDATE     
        ,   10          AS  LBKUM       
        ,   5.3         AS  VERPR       
        ,   10.5        AS  STPRS       
        FROM DUMMY
    ;

END;
```

It works fine on its own.
But when I try to inject it inside a `lateral join`, I get an error :

```
DO
BEGIN

    tbl_MATNR_LIST =
        SELECT '000000000000824151' AS MATNR , '92' AS div , '20220715' AS  VALDATE FROM dummy
        ;



    SELECT
        tbl_MATNR_LIST. *
    FROM    :tbl_MATNR_LIST     tbl_MATNR_LIST ,
    LATERAL(
        SELECT *
        FROM F__ITEM_MBEW(
                '000000000000824151'
            ,   '92'
            ,   '20220715'
            )
    ) MBEW
    ;

END;  



DataSource.Error : ODBC: ERROR [S1000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] General error;318 decimal precision specifier is out of range: -1: (1 to 38)
```

How can I fix it?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The error message

> `DataSource.Error : ODBC: ERROR [S1000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] General error;318 decimal precision specifier is out of range: -1: (1 to 38)`

can easily be fixed by specifying the decimal data type lengths in the user defined function:

```
   TABLE(
        VALDATE     NVARCHAR(08)
    ,   LBKUM       INTEGER
    ,   VERPR       DECIMAL (10, 2)
    ,   STPRS       DECIMAL (10, 2)
    )
```

Unfortunately, that does not help with the overall goal: to use the UDF in the `LATERAL` join in a meaningful way.

What does work is something like this:

```
DO
BEGIN

    tbl_MATNR_LIST =
        SELECT '000000000000824151' AS MATNR 
               , '92' AS div
              , '20220715' AS  VALDATE 
        FROM dummy;

    SELECT
        tml. *
    FROM    :tbl_MATNR_LIST     tml 
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
         F__ITEM_MBEW(     '000000000000824151'
                        ,   '92'
                        ,   '20220715') 
        ) MBEW;
END;
```

This does return the result, but obviously does not use any "lateral" references.
If one tries to make "grab stuff side-ways" this is the result:

```
[...]
     CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
             F__ITEM_MBEW(     '000000000000824151'
                            ,   tml.div
                            ,   '20220715') 
            ) MBEW;
[...]
```

`SQL Error [7] [HY000]: SAP DBTech JDBC: [7] (at 292): feature not supported: non-field expression with LATERAL: line 13 col 29 (at pos 292)`

At this point, I would guess that this way of using the LATERAL JOIN is just not supported (on version 2.00.057).